# Problems with html+css layout (positioning items)

Tags: html, css, flexbox, center, centering

I have this code:

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v5j3L6e9/

Basically, I have 6 boxes (Divs with an image and text over).

I'm trying to center the "bottomzone" (this could be for example a liquid layout, with the top zone as a header and then the main content, with a max-width)

The idea is that "bottomzone" has a fixed maximum width, so when the resolution is bigger, it should keep centered (meanwhile the "topzone" will be expanded with the resolution width).

I don't understand how to center the bottom zone without break the boxes positioning (the boxes have to maintain the distribution and keep centered).

Also, not sure if I did a good element hierarchy (pretty new on html+css).

Thanks.

```css
.topzone {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.topzone h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.bottomzone {
  margin-top: 50px;
  max-width: 800px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.bottomzone div {
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}
.bottomzone img {
  width: 100%;
}
.bottomzone div h3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="topzone">
  <h1>Title 1</h1>
  <h2>Title 2</h2>
</div>
<div class="bottomzone">
  <div>
    <img src="https://etc.usf.edu/clipart/21900/21988/square_21988_md.gif" alt="Just a box">
    <h3>Box 1</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://etc.usf.edu/clipart/21900/21988/square_21988_md.gif" alt="Just a box">
    <h3>Box 2</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://etc.usf.edu/clipart/21900/21988/square_21988_md.gif" alt="Just a box">
    <h3>Box 3</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://etc.usf.edu/clipart/21900/21988/square_21988_md.gif" alt="Just a box">
    <h3>Box 4</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://etc.usf.edu/clipart/21900/21988/square_21988_md.gif" alt="Just a box">
    <h3>Box 5</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://etc.usf.edu/clipart/21900/21988/square_21988_md.gif" alt="Just a box">
    <h3>Box 6</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use flex-box, you can simply use a wrapper element `centering-wrapper` and set `align-items: center` and `flex-direction: column` to center items horizontally.

```css
.centering-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.topzone {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.topzone h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.bottomzone {
  margin-top: 50px;
  max-width: 800px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.bottomzone div {
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}
.bottomzone img {
  width: 100%;
}
.bottomzone div h3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="topzone">
  <h1>Title 1</h1>
  <h2>Title 2</h2>
</div>
<div class="centering-wrapper">
  <div class="bottomzone">
    <div>
      <img src="https://etc.usf.edu/clipart/21900/21988/square_21988_md.gif" alt="Just a box">
      <h3>Box 1</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://etc.usf.edu/clipart/21900/21988/square_21988_md.gif" alt="Just a box">
      <h3>Box 2</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://etc.usf.edu/clipart/21900/21988/square_21988_md.gif" alt="Just a box">
      <h3>Box 3</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://etc.usf.edu/clipart/21900/21988/square_21988_md.gif" alt="Just a box">
      <h3>Box 4</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://etc.usf.edu/clipart/21900/21988/square_21988_md.gif" alt="Just a box">
      <h3>Box 5</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://etc.usf.edu/clipart/21900/21988/square_21988_md.gif" alt="Just a box">
      <h3>Box 6</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.
The problem on this, is that if I add a second zone after "bottomzone" (for example, "bottomzone2").. and I put it in column.
I does not work anymore. 
Example: https://jsfiddle.net/fjbgoqr0/2/

Comment: You need to change `justify-content` to `align-items`, because you are using `flex-direction: column`

Answer (score 0):

Add these CSS rules to the `.bottomzone` selector:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

This ensures that the browser calculates the same amount of space to use for the left and right margin. Since you use `margin-top` in your code, you could simplify it like this:

```
.bottomzone {
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  ...
}
```

where 0 is for the bottom margin.